# Is it Zariski closed: The set of matrices for which the first column is in the span of the other columns

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Is the set of matrices $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ for which the first column of $M$ is contained in the span of the other columns of $M$ Zariski closed?

Comment: Have you tried the case with just two columns?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in general is "no." When $m=2$ and $n=1$, this is $(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus V(x_2)) \cup \{(0,0)\}$, which is not Zariski closed.